# Keep highlite list item with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, list, user-interface

i am implementing a splitview using the new fragment from Google (Android 3).

when user choose something from the list it is show value in the details area and **keep list item highlight**.

when i used array adapter it is keep list  item focused after adding the following:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
getListView().setItemChecked(postition, true);
```

but when i change to use database using **SimpleCursorAdapter** and custom row xml file it is highlight just when i press.

"i want to keep highlight item in list view"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the activated style for your list row. The catch is that this is only available on API Level 11 and higher.

One way to do this is to use two separate styles. In `res/values-v11/styles.xml`, you could have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="activated" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Whereas `res/values/styles.xml` you would have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="activated">
  </style>
</resources>
```

Your row layout would then use that `activated` style, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  style="@style/activated"
/>
```

Combined with your existing `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` logic, this will leave your row activated after it is tapped.

Comment: THANKS I WILL CHECK IT AND BACK TO U WITH QUESTION OR SET AS ACCEPT.

Comment: thanks it is worked but how to change the color of mark and what is the meaning of values-v11

Comment: @ahmed: "how to change the color of mark" -- change what the `android:background` value in the style points to. Right now, it points to a value (`android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator`) from a system-defined theme. "what is the meaning of values-v11" -- Android will use resources in that directory on devices with API Level 11 and higher. Older devices will ignore that directory.

Comment: Dunno who down voted this answer but it's absolutely correct.